# Splitting and Parsing formula String

Tags: java, string, split

I have below formula

```
(Trig01:BAO)/(((Trig01:COUNT*86400)-Trig01:UPI-Trig01:SOS)*2000)
```

I want to split and get output of staring values which are before colon only,

Final output need as -

```
{ "BAO","COUNT","UPI","SOS" }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: And what you tried already?

Comment: http://regex101.com/

Comment: By the way if you never heard of regex google: regex capture groups.

Comment: @dici: Are you editing the question without reading it? "before colon only" original output was ok and you modified it!

Comment: @Betlista I thought it was what the OP really meant. `finalArr [] String={Trig01,Trig01,Trig01,Trig01}` makes no sense. What is it ? Obviously not Java code. Looking at Braj answer, he understood the question like I did. Otherwise, the question becomes : *How to count the number of occurrences of a substring ?* and it is totally different

Comment: Or Braj just answered what you asked and not what OP asked...

Comment: @Betlista That's a possibility. But what would be the point of retrieving an array entirely filled by the same value ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [**Positive Lookbehind**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in below regex pattern to get all the alphanumeric character after colon

```
(?<=:)[^\W]+
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/tY7yX7/2)

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    :                        ':'
  )                        end of look-behind
  [^\W]+                   any character except: non-word characters
                           (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
```

Sample code:

```
String str="(Trig01:BAO)/(((Trig01:COUNT*86400)-Trig01:UPI-Trig01:SOS)*2000)";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(?<=:)[^\\W]+");
Matcher m=p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: +1, and the answer would be even better if it included th way to extract the groups in Java using this regex, as it is not so straightforward for someone who never did it

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex, try this:

```
public static List<String> extractSubstringsFromAllMatches(String sourceString, String pattern) {
    Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = regexPattern.matcher(sourceString);
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matches.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Get the results you require by calling:

```
extractSubstringsFromAllMatches(YourString,":(\\w*)\\W")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-line solution:

```
String[] arr = str.replaceAll("^.*?(?=\\w+:)|:[^:]*$", "").split(":.*?(?=\\w+(:|$))");
```

This works by first stripping off the leading and trailing non-target chars, then splitting on the intervening chars. Matching is done using look aheads, which assert, but font capture, that a word followed by a colon follows.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String str = "(Trig01:BAO)/(((Trig02:COUNT*86400)-Trig03:UPI-Trig04:SOS)*2000)";
String[] arr = str.replaceAll("^.*?(?=\\w+:)|:[^:]*$", "").split(":.*?(?=\\w+(:|$))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[Trig01, Trig02, Trig03, Trig04]
```

Comment: @Betlista I have fixed the code, which has been tested and works as expected. Actually, the original problem not a missing bracket, but an extra one. Inadequate some other minor changes too.